# Custom model binder - get post variables with same name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, custom-model-binder

I'm building a custom model binder in ASP.NET, and in my post variables I have couple of them with same name.
Example:
website.com?person=1&person=3&person=6

Currently I'm using request.Form.Get("name") syntax to get variables, but it returns string, not list of strings, which I need.
How can I get all variables in list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your model binder:

```
var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
string[] values = request.Params.GetValues("Name");
```

**Note:**

- [`Request.Params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params(v=vs.110).aspx) gets a combined collection of `QueryString`, `Form`, `Cookies`, and `ServerVariables` items, and this way you can use your model binder for both query string and form data.
- [`GetValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba5htte(v=vs.110).aspx) gets the values associated with the specified key from the collection.

Answer (score 1):

`request.Form.Get("person")` will give you a string. But if you have more than one form elements with same name ,*person*, It will give you a comma separated string of values for items with person name. So you need to create an array from that using `Split()` method.

```
var s = request.Form.Get("person");  // s will have the value like "shyju,scott,sam"
var personArray= s.Split(',');
```